# How to bypass password executing a pkill in a script php executed from browser?

Tags: php, mozilla, sudo, kill, sudoers

I have to execute a php script from mozilla. In this script I need to kill a process, using the command sudo pkill nameofprocess.
From terminal, it requires me the password, and all is ok. But from browser, I haven't the possibility to insert the password.
Does it exist a way to avoid the password only for the command sudo pkill nameofprocess?

I tried to modify /etc/sudoers with sudo visudo, and I insert this line:
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/kill , where user is my name. In fact, if I write from terminal sudo pkill nameofprocess, it doesn't require me the password.

But, nothing happen from browser. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your webserver is likely running under a different user. The thing you do can still *scary* if not executed right and the server is accessable from the outside!

Comment: I agree, probably it is running under a different user. Please can you explain me better about the thing that I've to do? Thanks

Comment: find out under what user your server or php executable are running and adjust the command with that information. However, you should be aware that you are exposing your server to additional risks if user input and/or public access is involved.

Comment: SOLVED: I put the user of apache instead of user, using ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks for information. It is just a test, after that I will cancel all thes permession.